# How to call a full html page into a React component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bioinformatics

I've created an html file with an R package that is called BioCircos (represents defense systems on a genome). The html file includes an  tag that contains the Circos graph and scripts, that lets the user see more information in hover mode.
I'm sending the file through Flask API to React.js Component in order to view it on the application.
However, I can only present the picture without the scripts.
I have tried the below steps:

1. sending the entire html page to the component and used dangerouslySetInnerHTML or InnerHTML.
2. send partial html file that includes only the  and his parent  tags, and two related scripts, moreover I've put 5 more related scripts to the head tag of the application.
   I'm attaching the react component we want to put the picture in, and the html file in the link (it's too big for here).

Link to the HTML file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZAcK3o-4Kwmw2NzsRohO9IqjFheYSwU-/view?usp=sharing

### StrainCircos

```
    import React, {Component} from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    import InnerHTML from 'dangerously-set-html-content'
    
    class CircosStrain extends Component {
        state = {
            file: null,
            loaded: false
        };
    
    
        componentDidMount() {
            axios
                .get(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:8801/api/v1/strains/strainCircos/" + this.props.svnn,
                )
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({file: response.data});
                    this.setState({loaded: true})
                });
    
        }
    
        render() {
            // return (<iframe dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.file}}/>);
    
            return (
               // <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.file }}/>
               <InnerHTML html={this.state.file} />
            )
        }
    
    }
    
    export default CircosStrain;
```

Comment: I’d simply use `<iframe src={url} />`

Comment: I think this should be possible: `render() { {this.state.file} }` assuming this.state.file is a html file

Comment: thanks for your comment @hackape, I don't store the files on separate url. they are stored on ftp in my server.

Comment: @DFSFOT react blocks the scripts that are in the file... therefore I tried to use a workaround but without any success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the `iframe` approach would be easier.

The problem in the commented-out iframe approach is trying to set the iframe content using the innerHTML property. If the content you want to display is available through a URL, like in the example, it would be easiest to just set the iframe `src` attribute.

```
<iframe src={"http://127.0.0.1:8801/api/v1/strains/strainCircos/" + this.props.svnn}/>
```

If you cannot use the `src` attribute (for example if you want to use content which is not available through a URL or you need to modify the content after retrieving it), you could perhaps use the [`srcdoc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc) attribute.

```
<iframe srcdoc={this.state.file}/>
```

Or, if you need to support Internet Explorer, which does not support the `srcdoc` attribute, you could construct a [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

Comment: Works Perfect! Thank you.